# Lua Index Expected, got function

Tags: lua

The `data` variable is a parameter in a function. `sheeple` is an instantiated table. I printed out the type of `id` and `data` which printed "number" and then "string" respectively. However, upon the execution of `sheeple[id]=data`, I get the error "index expected, got function." Thank you for any help.

```
    local id = 0
    local tmp  = data:sub(8)
    tmp = tmp:sub(1,tmp:find("[^0-9]")-1)
    id = tonumber(tmp) 
    queue(id)
    print(type(id))
    print(type(data))
    sheeple[id]=data
```

Comment: Could you provide some more info? Is there any other value called `id`, which is a function(just a guess)? Do you have a backtrace?

Comment: There are no other variables by the name of id at all. I am not sure what a backtrace is.

Comment: It seems that `sheeple` is doing something especial with indexing. Look at its metatable, especially the __index and __newindex methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upon further review of my code. Embarrassingly, `sheeple` was also the name of the function that the code segment was in.

Comment: Can a moderator close this question? I am not able to accept my own answer after two days.

Comment: I thought so as well, but upon capitalizing the table value's name the error went away.